# Dharma residuals vs predictors interperation of dashed lines

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, diagnostics

I'm creating diagnostics for my glmmTMB model using DHARMa, and, while I understand most of the lines, I have problems interpreting scaled residual versus predictor variables: there is a red dashed line. Any advice on interpretation?

Example of residual vs one of the predictor plots:

[image: example of residual vs one of the predictor plots]

Let me know if you need more information to give me an answer.

Comment: I think you might get more responses by asking on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). "*Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization.*"

Answer (score 1):

The red dashed line is (to my knowledge) simply a non-parametric estimator for the average. In the perfect world scenario, we would expect it to be 0.

In the real world, we expect not to see any systematic deviations from 0. Yours looks rather good here. It oscillates between 0 at random, and only in the area where information is lacking ( `pred > 2.5` ) it starts to deviate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/issues/75). Shortly, what you see is a nonparametric smoother that is the default for large datasets. You can get a more intuitive plot by specifying `quantreg = T`